# AngularStrap Select and ng-options don't work well using dynamic array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angular-strap, bootstrap-select

I'm using AngularJS with AngularStrap (directive Select, based on Bootstrap-Select made by Silvio Moreto). I have the next problem:

I have an array of car brands. Using ng-options, I put them like options in a select. 
By other way, when I select an option (car brand), I get the different models of this car brand, and show them like options in another select.

The problem is when I'm using the AngularStrap directive select, it doesn't work well. The first time i select a car brand, it works fine, but the next selected option (car brand), it shows the models of the car brand selected and the first model of the previous car brand selected.

When I don't use AngularStrap select it works well, therefore i think the problem is in AngularStrap select.

Thanks for your help.

My code is the next:

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="selectBrand" ng-options="carBrand.id as boatBrand.name for boatBrand in boatBrands" bs-select >
<optionvalue="">CarBrand</option>
</select> 

<select ng-model="selectModel" ng-options="carModel.id as carModel.name for boatModel in carModels" bs-select>
<option value="">CarModel</option>
</select>
```

Controller (JS):

```
 $scope.carBrands = carBrand.query();
 $scope.$watch('selectBrand', function() { 
    $scope.carModels = carModel.query({type_id: $scope.selectBrand});
 };
```

Comment: Not yet, I think the problem is because of bs-select directive. I reckon that I must modify this directive, but I don't know how yet.

Comment: ok, thanks. For now, I'm using the "refresh" from bootstrap select using jquery :)

Comment: Hi user237865, How do you do the refresh, only over the bs-select component or you refresh the all page?

Comment: Bootstrap Select refresh, like below
$(element).selectpicker('refresh');

Comment: May be you can update that as the solution for now, until angularStrap fixes it.

Comment: @user237865 - how do you trigger the refresh? seems like onChange, ngChange or watch don't work because of this issue...

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but I had a similar problem with the Chosen Select plugin and a dynamic list of ng-options.   I finally resolved the problem by wrapping my options query inside of a $timeout.

```html
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.carModels = carModel.query({type_id: $scope.selectBrand});
            });
```

Comment: Answering old questions is good -- that's why we keep them around.  You don't need to apologize by prefixing your answer with "I realize this is old".

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to use the AngularStrap select support with a `select` element was to use ng-options and have *no option elements* as children of the `<select>`.